# How to apply a fully-covered horizontal overflow when child element is translated?

Tags: css, svg, overflow

I have a SVG chart located in a container. The CSS setting looks as follow:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, I have the problem that my chart is partially hidden. Therefore I apply a `overflow-x: auto`. But because I translate my chart to have the center of the chart being in the center of the viewport I cannot scroll to the left side of the chart (the scrollbar starts from the left cutoff point).

How can I make the chart being fully scrollable but at the same time keep the chart centered to the viewport?

**EDIT**

[Here is a sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhcy0z7w/)

Comment: Are you able to create a fiddle using your css,html etc

Comment: @DylanAnlezark I just added a fiddle

Comment: do you really need a min-width for your chart? you are facing the problem mainly for setting the min-width

Comment: @Irin Yes, because it includes many data point visualizations that would become too small to interact with when the chart is too small

Answer (score 0):

I could find a way using javascript and not using the css's arguments `translate` and `margin` on the chart. The js code scrolls the scrollbar automatically to its center (applied in a resize event handler it is also responsive). The code looks as follows:

```
if ((window.innerWidth * 0.95) < $("#chart").width()) {
            $("#container").scrollLeft(($("#chart").width() - ("#container").width()) /2);
        }
```